# Showing form errors beside form fields

Tags: php, html, mysql, model-view-controller, phalcon

Still learning Phalcon through the tutorials but I have an issue with displaying form error messages beside form fields.

The form code is as follows

```
<?php
use Phalcon\Forms\Form;
use Phalcon\Forms\Element\Text;
use Phalcon\Forms\Element\TextArea;
use Phalcon\Validation;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\PresenceOf;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Email;

class ContactForm extends Form
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        // Name
        $fullname = new Text('fullname');
        $fullname->setFilters(array('striptags', 'string'));
        $fullname->addValidators(array(
            new PresenceOf(array(
                'message' => 'Full Name is required'
            ))
        ));
        $this->add($fullname);

    // Email and text area fields with validators


/**
 * Prints messages for a specific element
 */
public function messages($name)
{
    if ($this->hasMessagesFor($name)) {
        foreach ($this->getMessagesFor($name) as $message) {
            $this->flash->error($message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The form in using volt engine is below

```
{{ form('pages/contact') }}
                <div class="controls controls-row">
                    {{ form.render('fullname') }}
                    {{ form.render('email') }}
                    <span class="help-inline error">{{ form.messages('fullname') }}</span>
                    <span class="help-inline error">{{ form.messages('email') }}</span>
                </div>

                <div class="controls">
                    <span class="help-inline error">{{ form.messages('comments') }}</span>
                    {{ form.render('comments') }}
                </div>
                <div class="controls">

                    {{ submit_button('Send It', 'class': 'btn btn-primary pull-right') }}
                </div>
        </form><!--end form-->
```

The code handling the form in the contactAction() is below

```
$form = new ContactForm();

        if ($this->request->isPost() == true)
        {
            if ($form->isValid($_POST)==false)
            {
                $form->messages("fullname");
                $form->messages("email");
                $form->messages("comments");

            }else
            {
                //send email
            }
        }
$this->view->form =$form
```

By calling the $form->messages("fullname") and for other fields the validation message will be printed using {{ flash.output() }} which is usually at the top of the page where I placed the code. How do I get the flash messages to display beside the form fields?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: I think you will need to set a variable in the controller using $this->view->setVar('fullname_error', $form->messages("fullname")); for each of the errors and display that variable where you want it.

Comment: Thanks Shad, Not working

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of playing around, I simply changed the messages function in the ContactForm class to return message and not flash the message.

```
public function messages($name)
{
    if ($this->hasMessagesFor($name)) {
        foreach ($this->getMessagesFor($name) as $message) {
            return '<font color="FF0000">'.$message.'</font>';
        }
    }
}
```

other parts of the code still remains the same.

Comment: It just returns the first message and finish the job